# Setting my own cookies in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have a PHP script located in my Wordpress installation's root folder
`wordpress-root/includes/login.php`

When I login from the home page, I call this script via AJAX to log in a user.

This is what the script does:

```
if (eveything checks out)
{
    //set session variables to track user

    //generate a unique auth token
    //store auth token in db
    //set cookies   
    setcookie('email',$email,mktime(0,0,0,12,31,2012));
    setcookie('authtoken',$authtoken,mktime(0,0,0,12,31,2012));
}
```

The problem is everything above works fine, but the cookies won't get set. I can see the entry being made in the database, and no errors or warnings are being thrown.

From another script, I do

```
var_dump($_SESSION); var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

I can see the session variables I set, as well as a bunch of cookies wordpress is setting, but I can't see the cookies I just set.

Please note: The above login has nothing to do with Wordpress's login system. I'm creating my own login system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont' know why, but far too often, I figure out the answer to a problem just as I post the question to SO :/.

Anyways, got it to work by adding the remaining arguments for `setcookie`. I'm going it this way now:

```
setcookie('email',$email,mktime(0,0,0,12,31,2012),'/','.example.com');
```